# Synonym for unneccessary

Tags: synonyms, sentence

I want to write that we have opted to buy a tablet for $500, because the latest models are not necessary.  They are too powerful for our use or needed by other people who have heavier requirements.

I want to write it with a synonym of unnecessary.

We didn't select the latest model because it was "unnecessary" for us.

Comment: How about ***overkill***  (not a synonym of unnecessary, but works for your situation)

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might go with

**su·per·flu·ous**
/so͞oˈpərflo͞oəs/

adjective

unnecessary, especially through being more than enough.
"the purchaser should avoid asking for superfluous information"

or

**re·dun·dant**
/rəˈdəndənt/

adjective

not or no longer needed or useful
"many of the old skills had become redundant"